# Why wont my Javascript dialog box work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dialog

I've been trying for a very long time to get this dialog box to work. I've crawled google and had a look at numerous question on here. I just can't get it to work anyway shape or form. I'm trying to get a similar result to this one:
http://example.nemikor.com/basic-usage-of-the-jquery-ui-dialog/

I did try using the code in this source but I couldn't get that to work either.

This is the jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

     // Initialize my dialog
     $("#dialog").dialog({
       autoOpen: false,
       modal: true,
       buttons: {
       "OK":function() { // do something },
       "Cancel": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }
    }
});

 // Bind to the click event for my button and execute my function
       $("#x-button").click(function(){
       Foo.DoSomething();
       });
   });

       var Foo = {
       DoSomething: function(){
       $("#dialog").dialog("open");
     }
   }
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<div id="column1">
        <h2>
            Features</h2>
        <p>
            Click an image below to view more information on our products.</p>
        <img src="../Images/lockIcon.png" alt="Security" />
        <input id="x-button" type="button" />
        <p id="dialog" display="none">This is content!</p>
</div>
```

I've tried everything to get it to work but its not happening. The jQuery itself is from an answer posted to a similar question on here, I tried to use it after my own just gave up on life, if you could help me I would be greatly appreciative, and please note, I am new to Javascript/jQuery so please don't rip on me too bad.

Thanks.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Do you get errors?

Comment: Sorry that was a bit bland, I mean as in, when I press the button, nothing happens at all, no function runs or anything.

Comment: If this is the complete code, you haven't closed the first `{`. The JavaScript console should reveal the syntax error. You can avoid these kind of errors using a coherent indentation.

Comment: Have you tried stategically placed alert() statements to find out what gets called and what doesn't. Make sure you don't have two elements with the same Id on the page.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario I have used coherent indentation on the actual code, I just had to tweak it for this post because I thought it might mess up, sorry. I have closed it off now but it still doesn't seem to run the function.

Comment: I tried the code in jsFiddle and it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/BwEtt/ All I had to do was to take the OK button's `}` out of the comment line. (@Alvaro: The first `{` is closed properly in the middle of the code, it just looks wrong with that indentation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing brace is commented out here:

```
"OK":function() { // do something },
```

You need to be careful with closing parentheses and curly braces. There were more problems with them, I fixed them, the following works:

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

     // Initialize my dialog
     $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "OK":function() {},
            "Cancel": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }
        }
    }
    );

    // Bind to the click event for my button and execute my function
    $("#x-button").click(function(){
        Foo.DoSomething();
    });


    var Foo = {
        DoSomething: function(){
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        }
    }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>


<div id="column1">
        <h2>
            Features</h2>
        <p>
            Click an image below to view more information on our products.</p>
        <img src="../Images/lockIcon.png" alt="Security" />
        <input id="x-button" type="button" />
        <p id="dialog" display="none">This is content!</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an error on this line, since your end-of-line comment hides closing curly bracket from interpreter.

```
"OK":function() { // do something },
```

You need to remove it or replace with `/* do something */`.

This works for me:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.14/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                // Initialize my dialog
                $("#dialog").dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        "OK":function() { },
                        "Cancel": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }
                    }
                });

                // Bind to the click event for my button and execute my function
                $("#x-button").click(function(){
                    Foo.DoSomething();
                });
            });

            var Foo = {
                DoSomething: function(){
                    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="column1">
            <h2>Features</h2>
            <p>Click an image below to view more information on our products.</p>
            <img src="../Images/lockIcon.png" alt="Security" />
            <input id="x-button" type="button" />
            <p id="dialog" display="none">This is content!</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, i've tried that now, still no avail. The problem seems to be that the actual button doesn't run the function, I'm not sure whether i've referenced it correctly.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to attach jquery-ui script? :)

Answer (score -2):

Here is the solution
http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/04/08/basic-usage-of-the-jquery-ui-dialog/

Excerpt from that page:

> The simple solution to this problem is to instantiate the dialog with
>   autoOpen set to false and then call .dialog('open') in the event
>   handler.

```
$('#opener').click(function() {
        $dialog.dialog('open');
        // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
        return false;
    });
```